# Регулярные выражения в GWT

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, gwt

Можно ли как-то в GWT работать с регулярными выражениями? Пакет java.util.regex - недоступен. Я набросал приложение на Java (Awt+Swing), логика полностью работает. Теперь надо изучить GWT, потому что приложение задумывалось сделать для браузера. В моем приложении очень много регулярных выражений. Поэтому если в GWT всё-таки есть какой-то механизм для шаблонов, там используются такие же правила как в java.util.regex или нет? То есть будут ли работать все мои шаблоны точно также?

Answer (score 1):

В GWT надо использовать [`com.google.gwt.regexp.shared`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html) — согласно документации, регэкспы, как раз, совместимые с JS:

> The super-sourced GWT implementation simply calls on to the native Javascript classes.